# PHP Paging with MYSQL last page not working

Tags: php, mysql

I use the query below in order to paginate my page.
The sql db counts 48 records.

The $rec_limit = 9.
This will result in 6 pages.

5 pages containing 9 records.
the 6th last page containing 3 records.

```
$sql = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary ".
        "FROM employee ".
        "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
```

The problem is when trying the last offset for the last page (LIMIT 5,9) no records are displayed.
The other 5 previous pages are working fine, displaying 9 records.

Anyone has a clue how to fix this ? Thanks !

Comment: I would try echoing out `$sql` and check `$offset` and `$rec_limit` are what you think they are

Comment: if the total is 48, which is 5 x 9 = 45, 3 remaining records which tallies up to 48, you're last page should display 3 records where your limit on the last page, the 6th page should be LIMIT 46, 48 ? no?

Comment: when you said `for the last page (LIMIT 5,9)` I figured out that you must be thinking that the `offset` is in "pages" but actually it is in number of records. Should be `LIMIT 40, 9`

Answer (score -1):

if the total is 48, which is 5 x 9 = 45, 3 remaining records which tallies up to 48, you're last page should display 3 records where your limit on the last page, the 6th page should be LIMIT 46, 48 ? no?

Comment: the second parameter for limit is length, not last record number. So it should be `45, 9` which would give you records 45 to 54. If the last number is greater than the number of records, it will just return any remaining records.

Comment: he said The sql db counts 48 records.?

Comment: `LIMIT 46, 48` is saying "give me 48 records starting at number 46". Limit is defined as `LIMIT [start], [length]`. Also, the first row starts at zero. So starting out you want `LIMIT 0, 9` which will give you rows 0 to 8 (count of 9 starting at 0). The next page would be `LIMIT 9, 9` which will give you rows 9 to 17 (count of 9 starting at 9). So for the last page (page 6) it should be `$start = ($pageNum - 1) * $perPage;` or `LIMIT 45, 9`. My point with saying it would pull rows 45 to 54 is that is what the query will try to do but will stop at the end (row 47) if it hits that first.

Comment: i would have done it differently, LIMIT 46, 48 would be the last page displaying last 3 records starting from record 46 through 48

Comment: but if there were an additional 20 rows (ending at 68), `limit 46, 48` would get you rows 46 through 68. I think that is what you are misunderstanding. You are requesting for 48 rows to be pulled out. It will stop at number 48 because there are no rows after that, but you are saying "starting at row 46, give me the next 48 rows" or "give me rows 46 through 93".

Comment: why would there be additional rows? there's only 48. total rows = 48, per page give me 9 results, 9 x 5 = 48 pages, on the 6th page give me rows 46 through 48 which are only 3 rows. in the code you would put the sql as you would normally, but in the LIMIT there would be 1st page: LIMIT 0,9 2nd page: LIMIT: 9,18 3rd page: LIMIT 18,27 4th page LIMIT 27,36 5th page: LIMIT 36,45 and the last, 6th page show me: LIMIT 45,48. If there were additional rows, you would put that in a $var and deduct from the total and recalculate the entire thing

Comment: From the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html): `LIMIT {[offset,] row_count}` and `With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)`. Example from the manual: `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15`. As you can see, `LIMIT 5,10` returns rows 6-15. This isn't `LIMIT start row, stop row` it is `LIMIT start row, count of rows to return`.